# Error is coming in google api config file

Tags: php, config, translate

I have a config file which is not working. Errors are coming in the coding I use. This error is coming:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ')' in
>   /home4/hangup/public_html/funchio.com/google/src/config.php on line 39

This is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2010 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

global $apiConfig;
$apiConfig = array(
    // True if objects should be returned by the service classes.
    // False if associative arrays should be returned (default behavior).
    'use_objects' => false,

    // The application_name is included in the User-Agent HTTP header.
    'application_name' => 'Translate',

    // OAuth2 Settings, you can get these keys at https://code.google.com/apis/console
    'oauth2_client_id' => '730492884762.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'oauth2_client_secret' => '1h4a2MlzhFul7iVYG9UYst4v',
    'oauth2_redirect_uri' => 'none',

    // The developer key, you get this at https://code.google.com/apis/console
    'developer_key' => 'AIzaSyC4LplsAo4KM0o_zVzw3rxBckGgx3FRj5s',

    // Site name to show in the Google's OAuth 1 authentication screen.
    'site_name' => 'www.funchio.com,

    // Which Authentication, Storage and HTTP IO classes to use.
    'authClass'    => 'Google_OAuth2',
    'ioClass'      => 'Google_CurlIO',
    'cacheClass'   => 'Google_FileCache';

    // Don't change these unless you're working against a special development or testing environment.
    'basePath' => 'https://www.googleapis.com',

    // IO Class dependent configuration, you only have to configure the values
    // for the class that was configured as the ioClass above
    'ioFileCache_directory'  =>
        (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') ?
            sys_get_temp_dir() . '/Google_Client' :
        '/tmp/Google_Client'),

    // Definition of service specific values like scopes, oauth token URLs, etc
    'services' => array(
      'analytics' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
      'calendar' => array(
          'scope' => array(
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
          )
      ),
      'books' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books'),
      'latitude' => array(
          'scope' => array(
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/latitude.all.best',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/latitude.all.city',
          )
      ),
      'moderator' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/moderator'),
      'oauth2' => array(
          'scope' => array(
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
              'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
          )
      ),
      'plus' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'),
      'siteVerification' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification'),
      'tasks' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks'),
      'urlshortener' => array('scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener')
    )
);
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Terminate (Close) the string with an apostrophe, on this line:

`'site_name' => 'www.funchio.com,`

Change to:

`'site_name' => 'www.funchio.com',`

Comment: Now after improving this line another error is coming. The error is coming -
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /home4/hangup/public_html/funchio.com/google/src/config.php on line 41. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: You've got a semicolon that doesn't belong (needs a comma instead): `'cacheClass'   => 'Google_FileCache';` should be `'cacheClass'   => 'Google_FileCache',`